# Grub - Assign IP to given MAC Address

Tags: grub2, grub

I have a simple `grub.cfg`:

```
net_add_addr efinet1 efinet1 10.1.1.10

net_add_route default 10.2.1.100/32 'gw' 10.1.1.254
configfile (http,10.2.1.100:8080)/grub
```

As you can see the `net_add_addr` is statically configured to always use `efinet1`. However I want to write something as demonstrated below, to dynamically get the card based on the predefined MAC address I configure in the `grub.cfg`:

```
# mac address that I know I want to add the address to. Predefined MAC Address
set mac_address="00:00:00:00:00:01"

# by default no active card is selected
set active_card=""

for card in net_ls_cards; do
    # TODO: find a way to get mac address from $card and set $mac
    set mac=""
    # TODO: find way to get the card name for the given $card and set $name
    set name=""
    if [ "$mac" == "$mac_address" ]; then
        set active_card="$name"
        break
    fi
done

net_add_addr $active_card $active_card 10.1.1.10

net_add_route default 10.2.1.100/32 'gw' 10.1.1.254
configfile (http,10.2.1.100:8080)/grub
```

The reason I don't want to use a static card is because 80% of the time, thus far, `net_ls_cards` have been giving me inconsistent results. Here are some examples:

**Example 1:**

```
> net_ls_cards
efinet2 00:00:00:00:00:01
efinet1 00:00:00:00:00:02
efinet0 00:00:00:00:00:03
```

In this case I want `efinet2` to be selected and `$active_card` needs to be `$active_card=efinet2`

After a reboot I would sometimes get the following:

**Example 2:**

```
> net_ls_cards
efinet0 00:00:00:00:00:01
```

In this case I want `efinet0` to be selected and `$active_card` needs to be `$active_card=efinet0`

#### Answer Requirements

So basically what I'm asking is:

1. Is my syntax for the `for loop` correct?
2. How would I be able to extract the `card name` and `mac address` from this entry `efinet2 00:00:00:00:00:01` so that it ends up being `$name=efinet2` and `$mac=00:00:00:00:00:01`

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of NIC device naming moving about without a reconfig of the hardware - but it can happen when you change the cards about.

The way I've solved it in the past is via udev rules although how I did that at the time would not work EXACTLY the same way now....

The detected cards are listed in /sys/class/net/ . If you query these files you'll see that udev can see the MAC address, e.g.

```
udevadm info /sys/class/net/enp1s0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0x8168
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=r8169
E: ID_NET_LINK_FILE=/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
E: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx4ccc6a160bd3
E: ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp1s0
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Micro-Star INTL CO., LTD.
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:01:00.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_01_00_0
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Ethernet controller
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0x10ec
E: IFINDEX=2
E: INTERFACE=enp1s0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/enp1s0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1000132
```

Specifically here: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx4ccc6a160bd3

So if I were to add a udev rule (in /etc/udev/rules.d/) with something like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net",ACTION=="add",ATTR{ID_NET_NAME_MAC}=="enx4ccc6a160bd3",ATTR{type}=="1",NAME="extnic0"
```

I should (not tested) get a device with name extnic0 for this particular NIC - and the name would not be used for something else if the card was not present.

.....or just use DHCP with a static assignment :)